# android expandable listview retrieve data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can i use `firebase` to retrieve data for my `Expandable listview`. my `firebase` node is like this..

[image: Firebase Node]

Adapter class:

```
public class CustomExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> headerItem;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> childItem;


public CustomExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> headerItem, HashMap<String, List<String>> childItem) {
    this.context = context;
    this.headerItem = headerItem;
    this.childItem = childItem;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childItem.get(headerItem.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, null);
    }
    TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChildItem);
    tv.setText(childText);

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return childItem.get(headerItem.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return headerItem.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return headerItem.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_items, null);
    }
    TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemHeader);
    tv.setText(headerTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    CustomExpandableListViewAdapter customExpandableListViewAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("Expandable ListView Data");

        expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expLv);
        SetStandardGroups();
        customExpandableListViewAdapter = new CustomExpandableListViewAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(customExpandableListViewAdapter);
    }

    public void SetStandardGroups() {

        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            int counter = 0;
            List<String> childItem = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                final String headerTitle = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                listDataHeader.add(headerTitle);
                Log.e("TAG", headerTitle);

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String child = (String) ds.getValue();
                    childItem.add(child);
                }

                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), childItem);
                counter++;
                Log.e("TAG", "counter :" + counter);


                customExpandableListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The out put is this: 
[Out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBjdK.png)

and i need Task1 the header tittle of first item and its contains 8 child's  and like 2nd Task2 the header tittle of 2nd item and it will contains 5 child's
and 3rd Task3 the header tittle of 3rd item and will contain's 10 child how can i achieved please help me i new to firebase Thanks...

Comment: Can you show your adapter class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last i found the problem. the problem is that i create a single Object of ArrayList for child which runs 3 times and save all data in one Object, so i found out that i need to create ArrayList Object Accordingly to loop Turn's which is 3.
this is the code which is working now.

```
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            int counter = 0;
            List<String> childItem;

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                listDataHeader.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                Log.e("TAG", listDataHeader.get(counter));
                childItem = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String childNames = (String) ds.getValue();
                    Log.e("TAG", "childNames :" + childNames);
                    childItem.add(childNames);
                }

                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), childItem);
                counter++;
                Log.e("TAG", "counter :" + counter);

                customExpandableListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```