# Display Firebase data into Expandable List View

Tags: java, android, firebase, expandablelistview

I have Expandable List View in my app with is hardcoded. After getting to know Firebase database i want to add inside child item information from my database. I copyed code and node from here [android expandable listview retrieve data from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681307/android-expandable-listview-retrieve-data-from-firebase) and it worked perfectly fine. Here is the result:

[image: result]

My main Firebase node look like this:

[image: Firebase node]

How can i display data from my node? All information stored inside "campus", building and faculties are should be parent item. Building1 and Building2, same goes to faculty item, should be child items. How can i achieve my goal? Here is my Java code:

```
public class campus extends AppCompatActivity {

    CampusAdapter campusAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_campus);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("campus");

        expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.campusExpandableListView);
        SetStandardGroups();
        campusAdapter = new CampusAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(campusAdapter);
    }

    public void SetStandardGroups() {

        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            int counter = 0;
            List<String> childItem;

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                listDataHeader.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                Log.e("TAG", listDataHeader.get(counter));
                childItem = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String childNames = (String) ds.getValue();
                    Log.e("TAG", "childNames :" + childNames);
                    childItem.add(childNames);
                }

                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), childItem);
                counter++;
                Log.e("TAG", "counter :" + counter);

                campusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my Adapter java file:

```
public class CampusAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> headerItem;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> childItem;


    public CampusAdapter(Context context, List<String> headerItem, HashMap<String, List<String>> childItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.headerItem = headerItem;
        this.childItem = childItem;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childItem.get(headerItem.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.campusName);
        tv.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return childItem.get(headerItem.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return headerItem.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return headerItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
        tv.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

p.s i use Glide to display images

Comment: What data exactly do you want to add to your list?

Comment: I want to add Image(It's a link to my Firebase Storage) and Title(String) inside child item. I already have child_item.xml file

Answer (score 0):

This goes in your onCreate() of the main class (the one with the listView)

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("(campus/building");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
                String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                String image = ds.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                //TODO: add it to the expandable view with the link above who explains it
                ExpandableListView myExpList= (ExpandableListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.yourExpListView);

                ExpandableListAdapter adapter =
                (ExpandableListAdapter) myExpList.getExpandableListAdapter();

                ( (ExpandableListParentClass)adapter.getMParent().get(0) ).getParentChildren().add(title);

                ( (ExpandableListParentClass)adapter.getMParent().get(0) ).getParentChildren().add(image);
                //(change to get(0) which you parent want to get )
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    })
```

Then create a new java class called "ExpandableListAdapter" with following code:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements Filterable{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<ExpandableListParentClass<Object>> mParent;
private View view;


public ArrayList<Object> getMParent() {
    return mParent;
}



public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
     ArrayList<ExpandableListParentClass<Object>> parentList ) {
    this.mParent = parentList;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

// counts the number of group/parent items so the list knows how many
// times calls getGroupView() method
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mParent.size();
}

// counts the number of children items so the list knows how many times
// calls getChildView() method
public int getChildrenCount(int parentPosition) {
    int size =0;
    if(mParent.get(parentPosition).getParentChildren() != null){
    size = mParent.get(parentPosition).getParentChildren().size();
    }
    return size;
}

// gets the title of each parent/group
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return mParent.get(i).getParent();
}

// gets the name of each item
public Object getChild(int parentPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mParent.get(parentPosition).getParentChildren().get(childPosition);
}

public long getGroupId(int parentPosition) {
    return parentPosition;
}

public long getChildId(int i, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

// in this method you must set the text to see the parent/group on the list

public View getGroupView(int parentPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview, viewGroup, false);
    }

    return view;

}

// in this method you must set the text to see the children on the list

public View getChildView(int parentPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview, viewGroup, false);
    }



    // return the entire view
    return view;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}

}






  List<ExpandableListParentClass> arrayParents = new ArrayList<ExpandableListParentClass>();
  ExpandableListParentClass item = new ExpandableListParentClass();
  item.setParent(yourParentItem);
  item.setParentChildren( yourChildList);
```

Then create a new java class called "ExpandableListParentClass" with the following code:

```
public class ExpandableListParentClass{

    private Object parent;
    private ArrayList<Object> parentChildren;


    public ExpandableListParentClass() {
    }
    public ExpandableListParentClass(Object parent, ArrayList<Object> parentChildren) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.parentChildren = parentChildren;
    }

    public Object getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Object parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getParentChildren() {
        return parentChildren;
    }

    public void setParentChildren(ArrayList<Object> parentChildren) {
        this.parentChildren = parentChildren;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the code in link. If its not troublesome for you, can you write code?

Comment: It's a good idea about ScrollView. I could add RecyclerView inside them and display my Firebase data. But is there any way to put them inside something, that can expand?

Comment: I have personally never used a ExpandableListView. That's why I'm not that comfortable with it. But I have another idea: You have a button and when you click on it, a ScrollView apears on top of everything else. Like a dialog, but with a ScrollView. I have done something like that and it's not too difficult.

Comment: Or is there any Expandable Widget where i can put RecyclerView?

Comment: Ill start to edit my answer to contain all the code you need

Comment: What about now?